# Firebase - Send notification from device to device on node updates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android game where users can like or dislike other peoples answers. When they do so, a specific node gets updated on Firebase.

What is the most simple way to inform a player with a push notification (like : X liked your answer)? With Firebase console I can send notifications to all users but in this case I want only the related player to be informed.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to store list of user ids for user, liked post as a child of 'Post' record and instead of Firebase messaging just subscribe to update event of that post. Another solution - use group messaging (see samples)

Comment: That is what I do actually. The users can see a little red dot on the notification icon (like on Facebook) when they receive a new notification. What I really want to do is to inform the user with push notifications so that they can be informed even when the app is not running (like Whatsapp)